# Die if Data Not Exisits in php mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, die

I'm getting an error message when the data is not available in data base table. I would like to stop the qry search without getting an error when the data is not available. 
It works good if the data is available in table but not works while the data is not available. For an example, when i search this city name in my table the requested city's data's are not available in that table. During this time i'm getting an "Undefined variable" error.

```
<?php 
$city = 'chennai';

$cityQry ="SELECT * FROM area_data WHERE city ='$city' LIMIT 1";
$cityQryResult = mysql_query($cityQry);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cityQryResult)) {
$citypop = $row['population'];
}

?>
```

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: hello tomudding, thanks for reminding. this is a old website from my client. i will get update once i get a permission from my client. If you know how to fix the issue which i have asked plz tell me.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at that function http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: If the query fails add `or die('possible error message here')` after `mysql_query($cityQry)`. This will cause the script to "die", check [die() on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) for more information. And check the comment @knets made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try Below Code (Not Tested Yet) :

```
<?php
$city = 'chennai';
$cityQry ="SELECT * FROM area_data WHERE city ='$city'";
$result = mysqli_query($cityQry);
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count > 0)
{
    $cityQryResult = mysql_query($cityQry);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cityQryResult)) {
        $citypop = $row['population'];
    }
} else {
    echo "No Data Exists";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks RedZ.. your code works..

Comment: most welcome buddy @DineshDiNu

Answer (score 1):

Check if `mysql_num_rows` gives you count more than 0, If count is 0 call `die()`

```
$city = 'chennai';
$cityQry ="SELECT * FROM area_data WHERE city ='$city' LIMIT 1";
$cityQryResult = mysql_query($cityQry);
if(mysql_num_rows($cityQryResult) == 0)
{
    die("No Data Exists");
} else {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cityQryResult)) {
         $citypop = $row['population'];
    }
}
```